# bzgrep multiple bz2 files using a wildcard?

Tags: unix, wildcard, solaris

I used the following command to search in 25 files compressed with bzip2:

```
bzgrep -i <text string> syslog_info.2015-03-0
```

where `syslog_info.2015-03-0` is a wildcard used to match 
`syslog_info.2015-03-01.bz2`, `syslog_info.2015-03-02.bz2`, up to `syslog_info.2015-03-25.bz2`.

Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/bzgrep[66]: j=${i//\\/\\\\}: bad substitution
```

The man page for bzgrep wasn't very helpful.  Individual .bz2 files are searched with no problem so I suspect the problem is with using the wildcard.  Is there's a solution for this besides searching each file independently?

Thanks,

Kokanee

Comment: if you're `greping` files (bz or not), you have to include a search target, ie.  `bzgrep -i mySearchString files*` (Wild cards as  you describe shouldn't be a problem). Good luck.

Comment: The only way I see you getting the errors that you indicate is that there is more code than you are showing. To debug, work from something that is working and then get something that is broken. `bzgrep -i 'mySearch String' files*.bz2` should return results, unless you have 1000's and 1000s of `.bz2` files in 1 directory, but the error message for that case is pretty self-explanatory (like `command line too big` (or something) ;-) ) . Good luck.